# Stop reading a CSV file after a row C#

Tags: c#, csv

I have this bit of code where I start reading a CSV file after a certain line. I was wondering if there is a way to also stop reading a CSV file after a certain line. OR, is there a way to stop reading the CSV file after I read a specific string. Stopping before a certain row would be better but. Let me know what you think. If there even is a way.

```
public List<ResultantRead> processCSVFile()
{
    alist = File.ReadAllLines("C:/Users")
                .Skip(54);
                .Select(v => ResultantRead.readCsv(v))
                .ToList();
    return alist;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public IEnumerable<ResultantRead> processCSVFile()
{
    return File.ReadLines("C:/Users")
                    .Skip(54);
                    .Select(v => ResultantRead.readCsv(v));
}

//calling code
var result = processCSVFile().Take(5).ToList();
// result will only enumerate 59 rows (or less) from the file
```

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I didn't think of that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
alist = File.ReadLines("C:/Users").take(250);
```

I think that will tell it to stop after 250 lines, but I am not sure how that will jive with skip, as in, will it skip 54 lines then take the next 250 or take 250 lines and skip 54 of them.

I would give it a try